# Add variable to the result of re.search Python and replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find an integer after certain characters and before certain characters, and add an integer to that.

I have this.

```
import re
filedata = None

with open('doc.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

count = int(filedata.count('~')) # 454

m = re.search('~RR\*(\d+)\*', filedata); print(m)

with open('docresult.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)</pre>
```

So what I have to accomplish is add `count` to whatever digits are between `~RR\* XXX   *` and replace it.

So if at the beginning I had `~RR*120*` and my count is 50 I want the new file to say `~RR*170*`

I tried also with `re.compile` but had no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your computations (how 120+50 can yield 175 for instance), but here's a way to perform computations on your integers when they match your strange `~RR*<a number>*` pattern using `re.sub` with a *replacement function* instead of a replacement string.

The replacement function is called on a match with the match object as sole parameter. It must return the replacement string.

```
import re

global count
count = 50
filedata = "hello ~RR*120* foo ~RR*40*"

def repl_function(m):
    return str(int(m.group(1))+count+len(m.group(1)))

filedata = re.sub('(?<=~RR\*)(\d+)(?=\*)', repl_function, filedata)

print(filedata)
```

that stand-alone example prints:

```
hello ~RR*173* foo ~RR*92*
```

We see that the numbers have been extracted, computed, and replaced back in the original string. I have used non-consuming (lookbehind/lookahead) groups so only the digits are passed to the replacement string, and the wrapping pattern is kept in the updated string.

Comment: Thank you for the re.sub idea, works properly now.  Really appreciate your help!!